Plotly add_image vs add_layout_image
In Plotly, both figure.add_image and figure.add_layout_image allow you to add an image to a chart. It seems like add_layout_image is intended for "cosmetic" images that shouldn't belong to a specific legend item. Are there any other differences, and is there any significant difference in how these two methods are implemented in Plotly?

okay so i decided to put the differences in a jupyter notebook for you to execute and see the difference,Please Note:
add_layout_image is used to add images to the layout of the figure, allowing for precise control over the positioning and layering of the image.
add_image (not used here) would be used to add images directly to the figure, but it is less flexible in terms of positioning and layering compared to add_layout_image.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create a sequence of numbers from 0 to 9
x = np.arange(10)

# Set up a new figure and plotting area
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)

# Draw multiple lines on the same graph
# Each line will be a different multiple of x
for i in range(5):
    ax.plot(x, i * x, label='$y = %ix$' % i)

# Add a legend outside the main plot area
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.05))

# Display the graph
plt.show()

#pip install plotly

import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Start creating an interactive figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Add the first image to the figure
# This places a semi-transparent placeholder image on the graph
fig.add_layout_image(
    dict(
        source="https://via.placeholder.com/150",
        xref="x",
        yref="y",
        x=5,
        y=5,
        sizex=2,
        sizey=2,
        sizing="stretch",
        opacity=0.5,
        layer="below"
    )
)


 # Add a second image to the figure 
 # Positioned differently from the first image
 fig.add_layout_image(
     dict(
         source="https://via.placeholder.com/150",
         xref="x",
         yref="y",
         x=7,
         y=7,
         sizex=2,
         sizey=2,
         sizing="stretch",
         opacity=0.5,
         layer="below"
     )
 )
    
 # Set up the graph's viewing area
 fig.update_layout(
     xaxis=dict(range=[0, 10]),
     yaxis=dict(range=[0, 10])
 )
    
 # Show the interactive figure
 fig.show()



The images don't seem to be correct?
